# Puzzling double integration with nested trigonometric function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

Let D be the circle with origin in (0,0) and radius=1. Find the value of

$$\int\int_{D} [x\sin(x^4+y)+1] dx dy$$

I tried with polar coordinate system, therefore $-1 \leq \rho \leq +1 $ and $ 0\leq\theta\leq 2\pi $ (hoping it's correct), but I am obtaining a sinus function nested in another sinus one and I can't understand how to handle that. Please, can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: use cartesian coordinates.

Comment: @Kari How would you solved the nested trigonometric functions that OP is asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider that $x\sin(x^4+y)$ is an odd function in $x$ and therefore that for any given $y\in [-1, 1]$, $$\int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}} x\sin(x^4+y)\,\mathrm{d}x = 0$$ which tells us that $$\iint_D x\sin(x^4+y)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y = \int_{-1}^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}} x\sin(x^4+y)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y = 0$$ Therefore, we only need worry about the $1$. $$\iint_D 1\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y = \pi$$

Comment: How do you know that $\int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}} x\sin(x^4+y)\,\mathrm{d}x = 0$?

Comment: Because for any odd, integrable function $f$, $\int_{-a}^a f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = 0$.

Comment: Could you please provide me a link with that proof?

Comment: Sure: \begin{align*} \int_{-a}^a f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x &= \int_{-a}^0 f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_0^a f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x \\ &= \int_a^0 -f(-u)\,\mathrm{d}u+\int_0^a f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x \\ &= \int_a^0 f(u)\,\mathrm{d}u+\int_0^a f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x \\ &= -\int_0^a f(u)\,\mathrm{d}u+\int_0^a f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x \\ &= 0 \end{align*}

Comment: I guess that $ \int_a^0 -f(-u)du$ is $\int_{-a}^0 -f(-u)du$?

Comment: No, it's $\int_a^0$. When we change the variable of integration, the bounds go from $-a$ and $0$ to $a$ and $0$. Of course, for any $a$ and $b$, we have $\int_b^a = -\int_a^b$, so the rest of our proof is apparent from that.